# Is there a need or purpose for the non-monster books?

Tags: the-witcher-2

The monster-related Books grant you Knowledge of those monsters, but what about the books on say Dwarves, or Magic, or History?

I see they usually unlock entries in the Journal, but are there any objective benefits to there?  Do they give stat bonuses, or new dialog options, or plot-related abilities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the non-monster books that I've read have added options to my dialogue. It will give me an option that directly refers back to the book that I read.

I remember one conversation with Dethmold in Chapter 2 on Roche's path where an extra dialogue option was given based on a book. However, I have never received an ability or stat bonus from reading a book.

Comment: I'll add that I've since found some Rune related books in chapter 3 whose contents were required to complete a quest.